# MGWT AnimatingActivityManager

Tags: java, gwt, mgwt

**Environment:**
MGWT 2.0.0
GWT-PhoneGap 3.5.0.0
GWT 2.7.0
Java 1.7

**Error Message:**
"The constructor PlaceController(SimpleEventBus) is undefined"

**How:**
I converted my project from GWT 2.6.0 to GWT 2.7.0.

Issue:
Looks like com.googlecode.mgwt.mvp.client.AnimatingActivityManager is expecting a com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus, however the only way to instantiate PlaceController (com.google.gwt.place.shared.PlaceController) in GWT 2.7.0 is using com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus, which is a sub-type of com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus.

I guess that means MGWT needs to adjust the AnimatingActivityManager to accept the non web-bindery EventBus? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general with any GWT 2.6 to 2.7 conversion, make sure you do not have any straggling references to GWT 2.6. There was one 2.6 JAR file in my 2.7 implementation.